# IntelliJ Scala cannot build a simple project (SBT can)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ idea community edition 14.1.3 on my windows 7 machine.

I created a simple sbt project where the build.sbt file looks like

```
name := "SlickTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0-RC3",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.0.2"

)
```

Now I wrote a simple class

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Foo {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("foo")
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    val foo = conf.getString("derby.url")
    println(foo)
  }
}
```

I created a file called "application.conf" in the resources folder.

```
derby = {
  url = "foo"
}
```

Now if I go to command line and say `sbt clean compile run` I can see

```
D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest>sbt clean compile run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest\project
[info] Set current project to SlickTest (in build file:/D:/myapps/Scala/SlickTest/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 26, 2015 2:24:04 AM
[info] Updating {file:/D:/myapps/Scala/SlickTest/}slicktest...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed May 26, 2015 2:24:07 AM
[info] Running Foo
foo
foo
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 26, 2015 2:24:07 AM

D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest>
```

but when I try to build the same project in Intellij idea I see

```
Error:scalac: Error: Could not find an output directory for D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest\src\main\scala-2.11\SlickTest.scala in List((D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\resources,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\resources,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\scala-2.11,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\scala,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\java,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\scala-2.11,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\scala,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\java,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes))
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Could not find an output directory for D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest\src\main\scala-2.11\SlickTest.scala in List((D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\resources,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\resources,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\scala-2.11,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\scala,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\test\java,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\scala-2.11,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\scala,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\src\main\java,D:\myapps\scala\SlickTest\target\scala-2.11\classes))    
    at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings$OutputDirs.outputDirFor(MutableSettings.scala:311)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.outputDirectory(BytecodeWriters.scala:26)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM.outputDirectory(GenASM.scala:23)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:41)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM.getFile(GenASM.scala:23)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JBuilder.writeIfNotTooBig(GenASM.scala:531)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JMirrorBuilder.genMirrorClass(GenASM.scala:2835)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.emitFor$1(GenASM.scala:193)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:203)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1500)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1487)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)    
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1580)    
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)    
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)    
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)    
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)    
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)    
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)    
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)    
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)    
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)    
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Does anyone know why can't IntelliJ build the same project when sbt can easily build it.

I searched for couple of could not find output directory threads but they did not help me because unlike others I don't have a capitalization error in my path or project name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Project settings and fill up the input with output path for this project, as on the image below.[image]

Comment: yes... that did it. thanks so much. I set it to `D:\myapps\Scala\SlickTest\target`