# Cannot build SBT project with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a fresh installation of IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3 (community edition). The only plugin I added is the Scala plugin. I created a new Scala project with SBT support (File -> New -> Project … -> Scala -> SBT) using SBT version 0.13.8 and Scala Version 2.11.7. Then I added a Hello world class to src/main/scala.
Building the project (Build -> Make Project) works first time. Changing the source and remaking the project (again with Build -> Make Project) results in the following error:

```
Error:scalac: Error: Could not find an output directory for D:\Temp\scala\untitled3\src\main\scala\Main.scala in List((D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\resource_managed\test,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\resources,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\resource_managed\main,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\resources,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\src_managed\test,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\scala-2.11,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\scala,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\java,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\src_managed\main,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\scala-2.11,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\scala,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\java,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes))
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Could not find an output directory for D:\Temp\scala\untitled3\src\main\scala\Main.scala in List((D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\resource_managed\test,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\resources,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\resource_managed\main,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\resources,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\src_managed\test,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\scala-2.11,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\scala,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\test\java,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\src_managed\main,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\scala-2.11,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\scala,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes), (D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\src\main\java,D:\temp\Scala\untitled3\target\scala-2.11\classes))

    at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings$OutputDirs.outputDirFor(MutableSettings.scala:311)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.outputDirectory(BytecodeWriters.scala:26)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM.outputDirectory(GenASM.scala:24)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:41)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM.getFile(GenASM.scala:24)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JBuilder.writeIfNotTooBig(GenASM.scala:528)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JMirrorBuilder.genMirrorClass(GenASM.scala:2833)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.emitFor$1(GenASM.scala:194)

    at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:204)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1501)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1486)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1481)

    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1582)

    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:115)

    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:94)

    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:22)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)

    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)

    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)

    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

Rebuilding the project (Build -> Rebuild) works. Building the project in the SBT Console or in a terminal window also works fine.
The solution proposed in this post [IntelliJ Scala cannot build a simple project (SBT can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452448/intellij-scala-cannot-build-a-simple-project-sbt-can) does not work for me, because the project’s compiler output path is set.

**EDIT:** Interestingly, when I close the project and import it as an SBT project erverything works as expected.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this, other than reimporting as a scala project? This is quite an annoying problem.

Comment: I've uninstalled IntelliJ 15 including all caches and settings, and installed IntelliJ 16 EAP with Scala EAP plugin. Things seem to work fine.

Comment: I installed IntelliJ16 EAP (IC-144.3891.8) after cleanly uninstalling version 15. But also the latest EAP version shows the behavior described above.

Comment: Guess I was lucky. I vaguely remember something similar a couple of years ago, and clean reinstalling sbt, and deleting .ivy2 and .m2 directories did something positive. Can't recall if that fixed it or not.

Comment: Today I tried it again because I wanted to check if the error is related to fact that I use a non-standard home directory (in the SBT settings dialog of IntelliJ I set the _VM parameters_ to `-Dsbt.ivy.home=<my-ivy-home>`). Surprisingly everthing works as expected now, even without making any changes to the ivy home directory. I suspect that my problem was related to some inconsistent state in the ivy cache.